# SQL PLUS doesn't launch

Tags: oracle, sqlplus, tns

I installed oracle 18 in my machine everything worked fine until recently i started to see SQLPLUS doesn't launch at all (exe opens but closes in a fraction of second).

1. I checked the oracle services and they are all running.
2. ORACLE_HOME is set to right path in the environment variables.
3. when i try to launch SQLPLUS from windows command line it does nothing.
4. tnsping to the SID returns OK.

Can anyone please help me on how to resolve this? thanks in advance.

> EDIT:
> I restarted my machine and all works fine.
> I shutdown -> start machine could see the same issue again.

Comment: What exe are you running?

Comment: SQLPLUS.exe from ORACLE_HOME\bin location.

Comment: @teja_98666 it would be easier to troubleshoot if you start sqlplus in cmd console, ie start cmd then start sqlplus in it, so in case of error you will see it in cmd

Comment: @SayanMalakshinov it neither returns any error nor launches SQLPLUS  

Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.17134.1667]  
(c) 2018 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.  

D:\WINDOWS.X64_180000_db_home\bin>sqlplus.exe  

D:\WINDOWS.X64_180000_db_home\bin>

Comment: Does the .exe file size look correct - or at least non-zero? Maybe it's been corrupted; have you applied patches recently, and if so did you get any errors? Is the timestamp of the .exe recent, and have other files changed too? Not much we can really diagnose from here...

Comment: @AlexPoole file size is non zero. I installed oracle couple of days ago and started seeing this since yesterday. No patches were installed

Comment: _it neither returns any error nor launches SQLPLUS_ so in the command prompt, when you hit enter, what do you see? Does it just go to the next line?